# How to prove or disprove: "If $ab\equiv 0 \pmod 7$, does that mean $a\equiv 0 \pmod 7$ or $b\equiv 0 \pmod 7$?"

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I have a homework problem for an introductory proofs class that asks the question in the title for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, asking also for the student to justify their answer.

It's clear to me that the question can be rephrased more simply as "If $7\mid ab$, does that mean $7\mid a$ or $7\mid b$?" So, I tried to prove that instead. I tried the following proof, but I'm almost certain that it's incorrect:

---

*Proof*. Suppose that $7\mid ab$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. Then,
$$ab = 7k$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $k = mn$, for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, which makes $ab = 7mn$. Going by cases, we have that either

1. $a = 7m$, $b = n$, or
2. $a = n$, $b = 7m$.

So, either $7\mid a$ or $7\mid b$.

---

The next problem on my homework asks to consider whether $6\mid ab$ implies $6\mid a$ or $6\mid b$; by this logic, it seems true since replacing 6 for 7 doesn't really change the logic of the proof, but my friends in the class told me that the second question is wrong. So, I'm assuming that my attempt at a proof is missing some complexity that I'm not seeing at the moment.

Is this the correct direction to go for a proof like this, or is there a way that's more straightforward? If this is the right direction, how could I make it more rigorous, and use a similar method to prove/disprove the next statement in my homework?

Comment: Hint: Take $a=3$ and $b=2$. Then $6|ab$, but $6\nmid a$ and $6 \nmid b$, which is a counterexample. Why is that?

Comment: Your cases actually beg the question.  You would need to formally justify why those are the only two cases, which would require you to prove the result you're ultimately trying to prove to justify that step.  Ultimately, you need to leverage the fact $7$ is a prime number in your proof.

Comment: Search for [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Comment: Tip: "\pmod p" renders $\pmod p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $7\mid ab$ and $7\nmid a$. Now, we want to show that $7\mid b$.

Since $7\nmid a$ and $7$ is a prime, we get that $(7,a)=1$. By [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), there exists $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$7r+sa=1$$

Multiplying both sides by $b$, we get $$7rb+sab=b$$

Since $7\mid7rb$ and $7\mid ab \implies 7\mid sab$, we get that the LHS is divisible by $7$. Hence, the right hand side must be divisible by $7$, so $7\mid b$, and we're done.

What this shows is that if any one of $a,b$ is not divisible by $7$, then the other must be divisible by $7$, which implies that $7\mid a$ **and/or** $7\mid b$.

Answer (score 1):

For any prime $p$ such that $p\mid ab$ then either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ thats due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic any number can be written uniquely as product of primes. So if $a=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{e_i}$ and $b=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{e_j}$ and $k = \prod_{r=1}^s p_r^{e_r}$ then we have
$$\prod_{i=1}p_i^{e_i} \prod_{j=1}^m p_{j}^{e_j} = p \prod_{r=1}^s p_r^{e_r}$$
By the uniqueness we should have $p_i = p$ for some $i$ or $p_j = 7$ for some $j$.

For the case of composite numbers thats not true clearly $6\mid 12 $ but $6\mid 4(3)$ but neither $6\mid 4$ nor $6\mid 4$

Edited (Just copied Nicholas solution):

> Assume $p\mid ab\Rightarrow ab=pk$ for some $k$ and assume that $p\nmid d a$ then $gcd(a,p) =1$ so by Bezout identity there exists $x,y$ such that $ax+py =1 $ multiply with $b$ we get $abx + bp y = b$ implies $p(kx + by) = b$ so $p\mid b$

Comment: Using fundamental theorem of arithmetic for this is often circular, since this is a crucial lemma in proving the fundamental theorem. The standard proof is with Bezout’s identity

Comment: @NicholasPriebe I cannot see how I can use $(a,b)=d$ implies there are $x,y$ s.t $ax+by = d$ in this problem. $p\mid ab$ where is the gcd here?

Comment: Assume that $p|ab$ and $p\nmid a$. Then, since $p$ is prime, $(a, p) = 1$, and we can solve $px + ay = 1$. Multiply both sides by $b$ to get $pbx + aby = b$, then note that $p$ divides all terms on the left, so $p|b$, as desired.

Comment: I've never seen the $e$ notation that you used within these products before. What does it mean?

Comment: @Mailbox it means the exponent like $45=3^2\cdot 5$ so $e=2$ for the prime $3$

Comment: @NicholasPriebe What do you mean by the ordered pair notation, is that the same as saying $\gcd(a, p) = 1$? If so, why does $p$ being prime imply that its greatest common divisor with a is 1? To me, it seems like the same is true for composite numbers.

Comment: @Mailbox Yeah, $(a, p) = 1$ is shorthand for $\operatorname{gcd}(a, p) = 1$. It's not just that $p$ is prime, it's that $p$ is prime and $p \nmid a$; the only factors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$, so for any integer $n$, $\gcd(p, n) \in \{1, p\}$. We know that $p$ is not a factor of $a$ (because $p \nmid a$), so the gcd must be $1$. This fails for composite numbers, since they have more factors. For example, $4 \nmid 6$, but the gcd is $2$.